# Is a passport required to travel between Guam and the Marshall Islands?

Tags: passports, guam, marshall-islands

Since the Marshall Islands are an Associated State of the US, do you require a passport to travel between Guam (a territory) and the Marshall Islands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Permanent Mission of the Republic of the Marshall Islands to the United Nations,](https://www.un.int/marshallislands/marshallislands/travel-marshall-islands)

> **All visitors must have a passport valid for at least six months,** must have sufficient funds for stay, and have an onward/return air or sea ticket.